# How to create directories recursively in curl or WebDav?

Tags: curl, recursion, webdav, nextcloud

I want to upload files to my nextcloud server. The problem is that I got an error. The first curl command should create the directory.

```
curl -u "$USER":"$PW" -X MKCOL "https://MYSERVER/remote.php/dav/files/$USER/$MANY_DIRECTORIES"
curl -u "$USER":"$PW" -T "$FILE" "https://MYSERVER/remote.php/dav/files/$USER/$MANY_DIRECTORIES/$FILE"
```

If `$MANY_DIRECTORIES` contains just one directory it works. But if this variable contains e.g. `/root/deep/deeper` and `deep` doesn't exist I got this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d:error xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://sabredav.org/ns">
  <s:exception>Sabre\DAV\Exception\Conflict</s:exception>
  <s:message>Parent node does not exist</s:message>
</d:error>
```

The second command throws this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d:error xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://sabredav.org/ns">
  <s:exception>Sabre\DAV\Exception\NotFound</s:exception>
  <s:message>File with name //test could not be located</s:message>
</d:error>
```

So how can I create the directories recursive to upload the file?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you create them one-by-one.

Comment: @JulianReschke: Thanks. I'll go through a loop.

Answer (score 5):

There is no option to create recursive directories, so I split the variable into an array and create the directories one by one.

```
IFS='/' read -r -a array <<<"$2"
for el in "${array[@]}"
do
        TEMP=$TEMP/$el
        curl -u "$USER:$PW" \
        -X MKCOL \
        "https://MYSERVER/remote.php/dav/files/$USER$TEMP"
done

curl -u "$USER:$PW" \
         -T "$1" "https://MYSERVER/remote.php/dav/files/$USER/$2/$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

In cy221's answer I would replace the first lines with

```
tree=$(find .  -mindepth 1 -type d | sed 's!^./!!')
for el in $tree; do 
    #etc.
done
```

This will of course not work for directories with spaces in it.
(sorry for using an answer instead of a comment, I couldn't get code formatting to work in a 'mere' comment).

Answer (score -2):

**There's no method for that behaviour!**

APROACH:

You need to create your own recursive function, that iterate over the directories path and create them one by one, like [cy221](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4120846/cy221) ilustrate in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42956353/2835520) above.